# Rapid Gui with Qt and Python Chaper4 Alert.pyw Not Popping

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

i'm starting to learn Qt and i'm currently doing the **alert.pyw** example. The example works just fine but i wanted to test it if it really works like it's described so when i pass the time parameter i acctually put in a time to be reached (for example, now it's 11:34 and i passed 11:35 or 11:36, just to be sure i tried a few times with longer waiting times and i actually waited after time it should have popped up for a few minutes).
Well, when the set time is reachead no window actually pop up to "Wake me up".
Is this because the code actually isn't meant to work or there is something weird going on?

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from future_builtins import *

import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import (QTime, QTimer, Qt, SIGNAL)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QLabel)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

try:
    due = QTime.currentTime()
    message = "Alert!"
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        raise ValueError
    hours, mins = sys.argv[1].split(":")
    due = QTime(int(hours), int(mins))
    if not due.isValid():
        raise ValueError
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        message = " ".join(sys.argv[2:])
except ValueError:
    message = "Usage: alert.pyw HH:MM [optional message]" # 24hr clock

while QTime.currentTime() < due:
    time.sleep(20) # 20 seconds

label = QLabel("<font color=red size=72><b>{0}</b></font>"
               .format(message))
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
label.show()
QTimer.singleShot(60000, app.quit) # 1 minute
app.exec_()
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Works for me on both Linux and WinXP. Try adding `print(QTime.currentTime(), due)` before the loop, and `print('waiting..')` within the loop - what output do you get?

Comment: After some more testing i realized that the problem was my wallpaper and the windows opened at that time... the code works perfectly it was just me that didn't see the window popping... sorry for the futile question!

Comment: It's little facepalm moments like this that help coders maintain their sanity :-)